# Awful performance after trying everything

Tags: drivers, nvidia, laptop, performance, mate

So i bought an old laptop (dell latitude e6500) upgraded to 4 gigs of ram, LXDE, 240gb kingston ssd with ubuntu mate 18.04, and a core 2 duo, first I am getting really bad performance on games like minecraft and geometry dash even on the lowest settings (minecraft b1.8 runs horrible aswell) first i thought it was my gpu drivers, so i did 340 but i had constant  crashes, after a while of trying I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04, that didnt help, so i manually installed driver 375, that didnt help, then I started thinking it was my cpu as my cpu for some reason after the upgrade was always maxed out on 100% even if it wasnt doing anything, i have installed programs like preload and disabled stuff and done mostly everything the internet says, i have done stuff internally like clean out the heat sync and fans, but i ran out of thermal paste, so i didn't apply any even tho there was some old stuff still on it, i also put another 2GB stick of ram also ran it with and without the dead battery installed, and tried everything i have found so far, any help? this is prob a stupid issue that im not smart enough to figure out. but any help is appreciated, my laptop feels like its gonna melt, and for some reason windows gets stuck at the dumb logo and wont proceed any further, so i cant upgrade the bios, i had reset the bios aswell any settings I should change in there? btw this laptop is fully functional (i think). thx in advanced

Answer (score 2):

That machine was mediocre even back in 2008 when it came out. It had an NVidia Quadro NVS 160M GPU (which you completely failed to mention) which was not really suitable for games even back then.

It will probably still make a decent machine for browsing the web or for office programs, but you seem to expect a speed daemon for gaming. That's simply unrealistic.

What are you comparing it against? What are your expectations? What did you measure, and how?

Do you have problems of the sort "it takes several seconds until a mouse click does anything" in the normal desktop? Or is it just game performance that you are missing?

Don't start tweaking BIOS settings. If you already did, do yourself the favour and revert everything to defaults. Unless you know very well what you are doing, you are probably only making things worse.

In all my 35 years of PC computing I have NEVER seen any useful documentation what all those crazy BIOS parameters (RAM timing etc.) do.

Comment: Also, "feels like it's gonna melt" could indicate a thermal problem that makes the CPU slow down. Is that only when you try games, or also when the desktop sits idle?

Comment: but it ran decent and never had always 100% cpu usage before the upgrade, and sorry for not mentioning the gpu, im not comparing it against anything, it just never had this problem before upgrading to 18.04.

Comment: Then check with `top` if there is any single process that uses 100% CPU for a long time (more than, say, 5 seconds or so). If it looks suspicious, try to kill it (you'll need root permissions for that). Check if this fixes the problem for the moment; if yes, let's find out together what that process is and if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my E6400. The laptop would slow down and get hot. I have upgraded the CPU, RAM, and a SSD, this machine should run very well, just not for gaming.
My solution was to remove the CPU heat-sink, and fan. Blow the dust off the motherboard, and blow out of the heat-sink and fan. Clean off the old thermal grease.Apply some good thermal grease to the CPU, GPU, and any other locations the heat-sink touches a chip. When you use the laptop, make sure the vents on the underside are not blocked. I also installed "CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor" on my taskbar, so I can check CPU speed and adjust if needed.

Comment: Heat build up is dangerous to CPU and GPU. It can cause temporary system outage or worse permanent damage.  If you want to measure your system's temperature, I'd suggest this link:  https://www.tecmint.com/monitor-cpu-and-gpu-temperature-in-ubuntu/